# Regex Not-Match Trailing Text

Tags: java, regex

When I use:

`(Act\sNo.\s\d+\sof\s\d+,[^\Q</ref>\E])`

Then this matches:

`Act No. 5 of 20,`

But this doesn't:

`<ref id="" status="" href="412">Act No. 5 of 20,</ref>`

**Which is correct.**

Now I want to do something similar. When I use:

`(Cap.\s\d+[^\Q</ref>\E])`

Then this matches:

`Cap. 412`

And so does this (**Even though it shouldn't**):

`<ref id="" status="" href="412">Cap. 412</ref>`

However, I've noticed that if I had a comma `,` after the `412` in both the regex and the text then it works like the example above. All in all, it's supposed to not include ones that have `</ref>` at the end. I've been testing here: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to change it as follows: `(Cap.\s\d+(?!.*</ref>))`

Answer (score 2):

Don't try regular expressions on HTML ever. First, parse the HTML via DOM functions and then use RegEx on values.

Answer (score 0):

`[^\Q</ref>\E]` should be `(?!\Q</ref>\E)`

characters within `[^\Q</ref>\E]` are treated individually

Comment: I changed it to: `(Cap.\s\d+(?!\Q</ref>\E))` on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it still matches the text and the `<ref>` tag?

Comment: what do you want after `Cap. 412` so that it matches `Cap. 412`..a space or end of line

Comment: @ThreaT make `\d+` `\d{3}` and it would do what you want..this happens because `\d+` matches all digits but since it matches `</ref>` it matches the string except the last digit

Comment: but it might not necessarily match 3 digits. It's x number of digits... It has to match `Cap X` **only** - not `Cap X</ref>`